# Type mismatch error when using ActiveCell.Row

Tags: excel, vba

Having some trouble here. On Sheet called "Start" I have column "I" In this column all the fields in the rows have the same dropdown:

- Sheet 1
- Sheet 2
- Sheet 3

I would like to open sheet in the workbook corresponding to the value from the dropdown. So for instance if I choose sheet 1 from the list "Sheet 1" in the workbook will open. As mentioned before these dropdown span across entire column "I" so no matter which row I select to use the dropdown I would like the same thing to happen. I have used Active Cell.Row but getting Type mismatch error:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        
If Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Sheet 1" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet 1").Visible = True
            Worksheets("Sheet 1").Activate
            Else
If Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Sheet 2" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet 2").Visible = True
            Worksheets("Sheet 2").Activate
            Else
If Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Sheet 3" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet 3").Visible = True
            Worksheets("Sheet 3").Activate
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: My first suspicion is that `Rows` don't have a `Value` property

Comment: `if target.value....`

Comment: What do you expect from `Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Value` code line?

Comment: @FaneDuru .value should read selected value from the dropdown. I have managed to get this working by adding ```If Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Sheet 1" Then``` to each condition respectively

Comment: Then, you can adapt your event in order to use only a code line: `Worksheets(Range("A" & Target.row).value).activate`. A better way would be to preliminarily check if the sheets exists...

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 9 Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Target.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

Note this will only work if `Target.Value` match the sheet name **exactly**

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Target` rather than `ActiveCell`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v1 As Long, v2 As String
    
    v1 = Target.Column
    v2 = Target.Value
    
    If v1 <> 9 Then Exit Sub
    If v2 = "Sheet 1" Or v2 = "Sheet 2" Or v2 = "Sheet 3" Then
            Worksheets(v2).Visible = True
            Worksheets(v2).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```